# how to restrict edit button in Share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

im an administrator on Share point 2013. but all staff can see and use the page edit button. how can i restrict or hide page edit button?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this means your staff has edit rights (contribute, edit, administrator) on this page library where the page is in (if default, it will be the Pages or SitePages library). Go to the library permission settings (go to the list via site content > on the library tab, click permissions) and modify it so they have read permissions. 
The button will not be visible anymore.